# Como fazer um slider contínuo?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Estou tentando fazer um slider contínuo como esse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="portfolio/img/thumb01.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="portfolio/img/thumb02.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="portfolio/img/thumb03.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="portfolio/img/thumb04.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="portfolio/img/thumb05.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="portfolio/img/thumb06.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" title="">
                <img src="portfolio/img/thumb07.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: isso pode te ajudar http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/2506/ é basicamente oque vc precisa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara pelas classes que vc está usando me parece que vc usa o OWL Caroucel, na documentação dele já tem um modelo para esse tipo de aplicação, chama `stagepadding` como vc pode consultar aqui: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/stagepadding.html

O modelo fica assim

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    stagePadding: 80, //aqui vc controla o espaçamento nas laterais direita e esquerda
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:false,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.owl-item {
    background-color: #D2527F;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div> Slide 1 </div>
    <div> Slide 2 </div>
    <div> Slide 3 </div>
    <div> Slide 4 </div>
    <div> Slide 5 </div>
</div>
```